# Не переведено "You've earned" (при получении нового знака)

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

При получении нового знака в профиле выходит плашка, в ней не переведено "You've earned":

[image: You've earned]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевел на transifex как "Вы получили знак". Надеюсь, этот текст в другом контексте не используется.

**Обновление**

Текущий вариант - "Вы заработали" от alexolut

Comment: Может быть еще с привилегией, но надо уточнить.

Comment: На мой взгляд, лучше поставить оригинальный перевод, без добавления дополнительных слов. Вдруг его ещё где будут использовать.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev, ок, сделал "Вы получили", хотя по-русски "Вы получили Наставник" как-то не очень звучит.

Comment: Тут знак отдельно от текста, так что интуитивно понятно, что получили награду в виде знака. На английском будет выходить "You've earned Refiner", что тоже некорректно.

Comment: Посмотрел в транзифексе: `earned` использовался как `заработали`, поэтому подправил перевод немного.

Comment: Предлагаю: «Вы награждены знаком». Перевод в первую очередь должен отображать не перевод слов, а смысл написанного.